# Keyboard layout error in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, keyboard-layout, language-support, ibus

I was installing Chinese pinyin input method on Ibus. But I found that the keyboard layout setting can not be used.

[image]

In addition, when I click that keyboard layout button, I got the following error

[image]

Then I tried to run `gkbd-keyboard-display` in terminal, but it returns error

```
mycomputer~%: (gkbd-keyboard-display:15972): GnomeKbdIndicator-CRITICAL **: 15:56:59.390: Either layout or group have to be specified
```

After running command `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources`, I got output

```
@a(ss) []
```

---

System: Ubuntu 18.04

Desktop: Gnome 3.28.4

---

Additional weird phenomina:

The user panel is corrupted. They are mis-placed, disfigured, and does not work  [image]

By executing `ls -la ~/.config/dconf`, it returns

```
myusername@mypc:~$ ls -la ~/.config/dconf
total 32
drwxr-xr-x  2 myusername myusername  4096 Jun  2 11:57 .
drwxr-xr-x 57 myusername myusername  4096 Jun  1 15:02 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 myusername myusername 20750 Jun  2 11:57 user
```

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Updated ^

Comment: The three input souces, which you have added according to _Settings_, should be listed when running that `gsettings()` command. So there are issues with the configuration of your machine, which are not necessarily related to the Chinese input method. If you want help with fixing those issues, I think you need to provide more examples of things which don't work as expected. A first check might be to confirm that you can update your packages without problems: `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Thanks, I agree with you. The `apt` works just fine. But I notice that my desktop user panel is broken (see updated question). I guess there is something wrong with my desktop.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson it gives `.`, `..`, and `user`

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Updated ^

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Truly sorry. I forgot to censor my username correctly. They are all `myusername`

Comment: I'm out of ideas, unfortunately. `~/.config/dconf/user`, where a lot of desktop configuration data - including the list of input sources - should be stored, seems to be writable by you and its timestamp changed as expected.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Thx, I would like to try reinstall/upgrade gnome. Do you think this is safe (revertable operation)?

Comment: Such things are never 100% safe. But make sure to backup your whole `$HOME` directory first. Revertable? Nope.

Comment: One thing you may want to try before reinstalling/upgrading is to create a new user, log in as that user, and check if the desktop issues are present for that user as well. If they are not, you know that the cause of the problems is somewhere in your `$HOME`, i.e. reinstalling/upgrading the whole system won't probably help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108786/discussion-between-nathan-explosion-and-gunnar-hjalmarsson).